# Fluid doesn't react on wind force field

Tags: fluid-simulation, force-fields, procedural

I baked fluid domain with wind force field inside it but it seems that the wind has no impact on fluid. What did I do wrong or there is supposed to be no result at all? in this case how to simulate the wind on the top of the water surface in particular spot? For example, I wanna turbulence on the water caused by helicopter.

[image: Scene solid]

Comment: As a tutorial link to the dynamic paint method mentioned below [Blind Illusionist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smArCTzxGpE) put together a good step by step.

Answer (score 2):

The Elbeem fluid simulator in Blender (fluid sim for 2.79 and earlier) doesn't support force fields.

You can use a particle system with Fluid physics and force fields but the challenge is getting a good surface.

1. Metaballs is one approach - see [Is there a way to render particles as if they were a single liquid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8499/is-there-a-way-to-render-particles-as-if-they-were-a-single-liquid?rq=1)
2. The Cubesurfer addon ([example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4Jd0AqnmXY)) was looking pretty good a few years ago but the development doesn't seem to have moved on from [Beta](http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/).

If you need to stay with the Elbeem simulator another option is to use dynamic paint to displace the surface by turning the fluid domain into a "canvas" and rig a object as a "brush" to follow the movement of the helicopter. I've made a very quick proof of concept and you can see it [here](https://vimeo.com/309406937). Note - very rough just to prove it could be done.

Finally, it looks like Mantaflow (the new Fluid simulator being developed) does support force fields. There are custom Mantaflow Blender builds for versions [2.79](http://graphicall.org/1236) and [2.8](http://graphicall.org/1240) that you can download. My experience from a small amount of playing with 2.79 is that Mantaflow was not very stable. I haven't tried the 2.8 version yet... use at own risk!