# Fluid Sim multi coloured domain

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to have 2 different coloured liquids splashing at each other, i have managed to colour one of them which colours both when i try to change the other it changes both. How do i get 2 different coloured in flows?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/different-materials-for-each-fluid-inflow

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are attempting to do *isn't yet supported* by the Blender Fluid Simulator. You can't have fluids with different properties/materials *interact* because the fluid properties and material are **attributes of the domain** rather than of the **inflow objects**.

As an alternative, you may choose to use Blender's [SPH Fluid Simulator](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/physics/fluid.html), which uses the particle system rather than the fluid sim. 
*Here's a previous answer to a question very similar to yours* : [Different materials for each fluid inflow?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/different-materials-for-each-fluid-inflow)