# simulate interaction of fluids with different viscosity

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, fluid-simulation

Like everybody else in this site I've been new to blender for quite some time...

I'm trying to do an animation to simulate a mix of paint blobs with different colors, like [Ebru Painting](https://www.google.com/search?q=ebru%20painting&safe=off&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6-9eDm7LNAhUQ4WMKHY2NDSoQsAQIJA&biw=1349&bih=920) or [Suminagashi](https://www.haikudeck.com/suminagashi--education-presentation-mCTTVbzpOs#slide4) marbling, based on mixing colored liquids with different levels of viscosity.

The idea is to have a drop of colored paint displace the surface, so that the colors don't really mix but create variable abstract fluid and organic shapes.

As an example please take 30 seconds to see this video by **garip ay** from minute 3:00 up to 3:30:

https://youtu.be/4dKy7HNU4vk?t=187

[image]
(image from the mentioned video)

I understand how to make [more than one fluid domain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/how-to-bake-multiple-fluid-simulations-in-one-scene) to create different colors but I can't think of a way to simulate the interaction between them.

Maybe there's a way to do this with dynamic paint... I just haven't used that tool very much.

Since this is a flat image it could also be done with some clever texturing... maybe?

How could I do something like this in blender?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5469/599

Comment: Possibly usefull to obtain some of the effects seen in the video : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/creating-a-black-hole-in-blender

Comment: Hmm, could they be multiple textures (on a plane) that have their boundaries distorted by another texture or object?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : I'm afraid I've not done much beyond scripting meshes at this point. I did once play with particle emitters and some constraint stuff hence this suggestion but this is a bit of a hack and may cost you more time then save you any.

Based off of the video you could try the following :

Setup a plane or may be even a cube with the top face removed. Using a particle emitter you could fill this cube at various locations to 'add ink' as it were. The tricky thing is then to make the particles emitted in a single addition cling to one another but repulsive to any prior and/or successive addition. That is for a single emission you want those particles to group in some way, perhaps there is some sort of elastic constraint you could apply. Then for separate emissions you basically want each addition to repel one another slightly.

You may have to make all emissions adhere to the bin/plate though, this is most easily by just doing things in the vertical direction.

Comment: Very interesting approach. Worth trying with boids and flocks

Answer (score 1):

I tried making a fluid distortion from metaballs on particles. Theres a material on the metaball that distorts based on the blobby surface geometry which looks like the paint mixing.

[image: swirls]

I made a plane that emits 2 sets of water particles from opposing edges then used wind force fields to mix them. I dressed the particles in metaballs.

[image: particles]

[image: metaballs on rig]

Then I apply a material that has distortion using Musgrave texture.

[image: swirl texture]

Answer (score -1):

This is not currently possible.  The only way to do something like this currently is to fake it in some fashion:

[How to bake multiple fluid simulations in one scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/how-to-bake-multiple-fluid-simulations-in-one-scene)