# Is it posible to mix materials in fluid simulation

Tags: materials, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to create a logo where balls of slime are thrown and splash to the logo, but I would like to have different materials for each ball of slime.

[image: This is an example with just one ball:]

Is thispossible? because I can't create more than one domain thus not able to assign different materials

Comment: what type of fluid are your balls of slime? Otherwise you could consider using a particle system

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/how-to-bake-multiple-fluid-simulations-in-one-scene and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/different-materials-for-each-fluid-inflow

Comment: @FacebFaceb they have the parameters for honey

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the fluid simulation, could be using a particle system:

1. First **add a colliding box**:
   [image]
2. Then **add fluid sources** (depends on the amount of balls of slime you want to use and what shape they are, in my example I use 2 cubes):
   [image]
3. In the physics tab, enable **Collision and set the Particle Damping Factor** to 1 (highlighted with blue). Also make sure to set the end time (highlight green):
   [image]
4. Then select a cube and add a particle system and tune the **Emission settings** highlighted in blue as you desire, but make sure to set **Emit from: Volume**:
   [image]
5. Then tune **Emitter geometry** and **Emitter object settings**, but make sure to choose **Physics: Fluid**:
   [image]
6. Next, select the other cube and add a new particle system by clicking the **right most plus** sign, then select the previous settings called **ParticleSettings** and click the plus sign next to it to make a copy:
   [image]
7. Then tune the Emission, Emitter geometry and Emitter object settings, but make sure **Emit from: Volume** and choose **Physics: Fluid**  as in steps 4 and 5.
8. Then add two UV spheres and assign material to each of them:
   [image]
9. Also enable **Colission** and make sure to set **ParticleDamping Factor** to 1:
   [image]
10. Then select a cube, in the **particlesystems settings**: **Render section**, choose **Object** and select the **name of the sphere** and tune the **size**:
    [image]
11. Then select the other cube and do the same:
    [image]
12. After some modifications, for example choosing the Viscocity value to 8, you may obtain the following result:
    [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I wasn't able to explain what I'm trying to achieve precisely. I have updated the question with a small animated gif to make it a little bit more clear. As you can see the ball splashes against the text as a mass object. If I use particles I think I can't achieve such a dense splash and particles will be seen in the animation (I'm trying to avoid that).